# asp. net without load page

Tags: asp.net

Here below response send my windows application to my site
http://www.abcd.com/response.aspx?name=bala

response page i dnt want to load.

in which event i write code to get the parameter like 'name'

in page load

```
dim str as string=request.querystring('name')
```

i get the name. but i dnt want to load that page.
all the response i want store any text file. it is possible with out load the page in asp.net?

Comment: please clarify, you will get downvoted very fast if you're not clear enough

Comment: Yeah I don't have the slightest clue what it is you need help with.

Comment: with out page load how to create one txt file in asp.net

Comment: what is request page stage in asp.net with event is suitable for that stage?

Comment: This question seems unclear to me.  The fact that the answers sounds like they're responding to four different questions supports my theory.  FWIW, if I had to make my best guess at what you're asking, I'd say that an HttpHandler is what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to load the page, you could do a Response.Redirect to another page.  Use Page_Init to handle this at a level above the Load event.

Comment: Without using a page (since you don't want to use Page_Load), you could create an HTTP Module which will look at the URL and take some appropriate action (such as writing to a text file).  You'll still need an endpoint for this, so maybe an HTTP Handler is more appropriate?  Sorry, I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the content-type of the page so it doesn't attempt to load in your browser, and instead opens a text file for you.  Something like this:

Here's the .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="myPage_export.aspx.vb" Inherits="myPage_export" %>
```

Here's the code-behind:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Configuration

Partial Class myPage_export
    Inherits system.web.ui.page

       Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

       dim str as string=request.querystring('name')
       If str = "whatever" THEN 'send text file instead
          mytxt = 'Open or Create your text file here

           myFileName = "testfile.txt"

           Response.ContentType = "application/txt" '<--verify the txt part -- I'm not sure if that's the correct code

           Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + myFileName)

           Response.Write(mytxt)
        Else 'let them open a web page
           response.redirect("some web page")
        End
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm not actually sure what you want -- but it sounds like you want to do something like this.  If not, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to send any response to client you can just send a 204 No Response http header. I think a one line code in your page_load will be enough.

```
Response.StatusCode = 204
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WebForms with ASP.NET, you're going to return a page of some description, because that's the way that the WebForms abstraction works. As Keith says, you can return a different page using Response.Redirect, but you'll return a page all the same.

This is the beauty of ASP.NET MVC and I recommend it over WebForms.

With WebForms, a URL refers to a resource that the server is expected to return.

With ASP.NET MVC, a URL describes an instruction to a controller.